# Error term of the Prime Number Theorem and the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: prime-number-theorem, nt.number-theory

I have read that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to

$\pi(x)=\text{Li}(x)+O(\sqrt{x}\log x)$

Is there an analogous statement saying the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to

$\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}+ O(f(x))\quad$ for some $f$

or

$\pi(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}+ g(x) + O(h(x))\quad$ for some elementary function $g$ and $h$

I'm guessing that $f$ could not possibly be $\sqrt{x}\log x$ because I plotted

$\frac{\text{Li}(x)-x/\log(x)}{\sqrt x\log x}$ and it looked like it grew without bound as $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Yes to the second one: g(x)=Li(x)-x/log x; h(x)=sqrt(x)log x

Comment: Changed my post to include that $g$ must be an elementary function.

Comment: and that assuming RH we can refine $\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ to $h(x) = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x} \log x)$ should come from the fact that we know there are $(C T+\mathcal{O}(1)) \ln T $ non-trivial zeros $Im(\rho) < T$ https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#La_bande_critique_et_l.27hypoth.C3.A8se_de_Riemann

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not hard to show that
$$\mathrm{Li}(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} \sum_{k=0}^{m - 1}{\frac{k!}{(\log x)^k}} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^{m + 1}}\right)$$
for any $m \geq 0$ (just use the definition of $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ and repeated integration by parts). Thus
$$\pi(x) = \frac{x}{\log x} \sum_{k=0}^{m - 1}{\frac{k!}{(\log x)^k}} + O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^{m + 1}}\right).$$
It is not possible to improve on this (this is true unconditionally; you don't even need the Riemann hypothesis). So $\mathrm{Li}(x)$ really is the "better" approximation to $\pi(x)$ compared to $x/\log x$.

Comment: so x is prime when floor(pi(x))<floor(pi(x+1))